# Service workers event listener - fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

I'd created a service worker by next code:

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

and get fine answer, and event 'install' emit in sw.js ok, but event 'fetch' never emit.

I use http-server (node js) with 80 (http) port, i've seen my request in DevTools Chrome and in console from http-server, but my service worker hadn't emitted any.

My service worker code:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
    console.log("event - install"); // OK
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (e) => {
    console.log("A"); // BAD
    return e.request;
});
```

I use this code in the end of body

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert("S");
  fetch("/svg.svg", {
    method: "GET"
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: The `fetch` event is triggered whenever you use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` from the client side. Where in your code are you doing that?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier sorry, i forgot add it, i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i decide my problem. I forgot to remove option 'Disable cache' in DevTools (in 'Network' tab) Chrome, i'd worked with this option yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

serviceworker must run in https protocol but http-server create a http server

Comment: but "In order to facilitate local development, localhost is considered a secure origin by browsers as well." - from dev mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: ok, i've tested my code in ngrok with https, and 'fetch' event did not emit to